# AnguarJS won't even run $scope message

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having an issue where angular doesn't seem to be working at all in my app.

Trying to run a message on index page with mainController, and won't even run this.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cj5pe43k/1/.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">

    <div id="test" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background:#000;width:100vw;height:100vh;color:#fff;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;"><p>{{message}}</p></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
})

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Main Controller Active';
})
```

Comment: Try opening browser's `developer tool > console` to see if any errors there

Comment: Never use `.min.js` files in development. Makes it substantially harder to debug the app.

Answer (score 1):

After checking your jsFiddle, it seems that you are including angular-ui-router, despite typing code for ngRoute. The error returned by the fiddle is a little bit hidden but clear: It can't find ngRoute module. And your attached files are having angular-ui-router included.

Are you following these steps? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

If you want to include ui router, please have a look here instead: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/index.html#/api/ui.router

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons:

- Angular is not there in the `<head>`.
- There's an error. Check the console for errors like "module 'app' is not available". This applies to both ngRoute and the main app(you'll need angular-route.js for the ngRoute module). If you use ui-router, you'll need angular-ui-router.js.

Comment: Angular is included in the head and there are no errors appearing in the console

Comment: @Nick see answer.

Answer (score -1):

you have loaded the ui-router URL .Try working with angular route cdn

otherwise use ui-routing

Comment: What? That didn't make any sense

Comment: try this cdn <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>